# My whole HDD is system reserved

Tags: windows, partitioning, system-reserved-partition

Well I've got a 750 GB Hihachi HDD. I've installed Ubuntu on one of it's partitions (space dedicated to it is 50 GB). Now all of the other space which will be about 643 GB has become System Reserved which I want to split it into some other partitions and install Windows 8.1 on it. I guess if I try to delete this partition, some critical manufacturer system data will vanish. How should I fix this problem? Should I boot a partition manager disk and shrink this System partition? Wouldn't system data be deleted in that case?

PS: This is my current partitioning state:
[image]

Comment: I think there shouldn't be any relation between HDD and manufacturer data (BIOS maybe), so I'll just try deleting the System partition and inform the result.

Comment: Have you tried to click on *Show details*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be nothing on that partition. BIOS is NOT stored on the HDD. Mostly probably when you installed Ubuntu, it must have created a SWAP memory that ended up being System Reserved.

My suggestion is:

1. Format the entire drive.
2. Install Windows
3. Then install Ubuntu

That way Ubuntu will detect Windows, create a good enough Swap location and also install GRUB.
Presently Windows will change the BOOT sector to load Windows and Grub will never load. This way you will not be able to access your Linux partition. To enable it, you will have to do some command line magic using Live CD to install GRUB.

Also make sure that the drive on which you want to install Windows is IDE 0 i.e. Drive 0. I have faced issues in the past installing Windows on drive which are not drive 0.